# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Can't Restart

Tags: nvidia, 16.04, restart, gpu, nvidia-prime

I am using Acer laptop. I have nvidia 940m. Whenever I restart laptop, my screen freeze and display breakdown intro pieces shown in the figure below. 
I tried editing `grub reboot=pci , acpi , bios , efi` etc  but none worked.

[image]

Ubuntu: 16.04
GPU: NVidia 940m

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 is not officially released yet. So, this website cannot cover your question. Please download the stable version of Ubuntu (16.04 will be released on 21st Apr)

Comment: @MostafaAhangarha As the 16.04 release is in just a few hours, I think suggesting to install another version is unproductive at this point as the OP's system will be full release very shortly.

Comment: Asad, what is your GPU driver? Did you install the Nvidia driver?

Comment: nvidia 940m & yes i did install driver from additional driver option.

Answer (score 0):

I also has this problem. but it's solved, when i replace my **kernal to 4.4.15**.

link for [kernal 4.4.15](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.4.15/)

- download the link on it.
- if your computer is 64 bit download first 4 link.
- and extract to a specific folder.
- open a terminal from there.
- and write the code.

  sudo dpkg -i *.deb

that's all.....

Comment: i think your comment missing, cos you dont know which kernel version used by owner of question. my recommandation is firstly, upgrading your system by sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade

Answer (score 0):

You can restart with the command of restarting.

```
man reboot
```

to shut down

> shutdown -r now